# Where is this dome in Delhi?

Tags: india, where-on-earth, new-delhi

This is an image from an 1986 Tamil movie, [Mouna Raagam, (at 0:26 in this video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxWhMkFB96M), which was supposedly shot in Delhi.

A paste into [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en_GB&tbs=sbi%3AAMhZZiufRhyynf3Wg6a52x_1WBREy06_1j7n6nuu1jf5aHUyiZCuUvFq_1XL5tE_1dC19RQkcMHw3Kx8mzOKaGJfPUskkteOBd1KVfXdzsgLU5wfxLhXhIslcqKVuNqZyZMZPu1cHacgi9_1cIaS_10PrWS9yt5j98OgIAbkCDs42jMM2YPOCVp6xKTdZ3WXPhHeyoNySBCMcNl_1tFj0OqUq7Hji_1P_1wbOqv4QqVEst1QWWPY30qekSu36tF0m7zopT11kasEbn65btixVGshOfTU96bBRSk1P4XV_1FW_13xV-USoInGv4_1yLKBN5WBOhjOXqnfMpZ67ztM3exhgp_1C-Go61OxwAG88Fy8zuA&sxsrf=ALeKk02gW-qe_rWiGwLzn3qrpgkqzAXhjg%3A1615330833911&ei=Ef5HYIGUN-Cd1fAPvOGC2As&q=delhi++agra&oq=delhi++agra&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEJECMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOgQILhBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgUILhCRAjoOCC4QsQMQxwEQrwEQkQI6AgguOgoILhDHARCvARAKOggILhDHARCvAVD1B1jyFGDsFWgBcAB4AIABoAGIAcMGkgEDNS4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjB4LKkqKTvAhXgThUIHbywALsQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) throws a number of domes in Delhi, but the top is somewhat flat in the picture. The structure hoisting the Indian flag in front also adds to the confusion about the location. There is [a site](http://wherewasitshot.com/mouna-raagam/) pertaining to locating places in movies, which gives India Gate and Akbar's tomb in Agra, neither of which seem to match with the structure in the image.

Which particular dome is this?[image: Delhi Dome]

Answer (score 23):

It's the old Viceroy House, now known as [Rashtrapati Bhavan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashtrapati_Bhavan).

If you scroll down the wikipedia page (linked above), you'll see a similar image that shows more of the building.